# Trying to debug this program. Having extreme difficulty doing so

Tags: java, debugging

```
public class DebugThree4
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int myCredits = 13;
    int yourCredits = 17;
    double rate = 75.84;
    System.out.println("My tuition:");
    tuitionBill(myCredits, rate);
    System.out.println("Your tuition:");
    tuitionBill(myCredits, rate);
  }

  public static void tuitionBill(double r)
  {
    System.out.println("Total due " + (r*c));
  }

}
```

I get errors like: method tuitonbill in class cannot be applied to given types: 
If someone could explain in detail as to how to make this work that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're passing 2 parameters to a method that accepts only 1 parameter.

Comment: I am not sure if this falls into the "off-topic->typographical error/minor error unlikely to be helpful for others", but I voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

When you call this method `tuitionBill(myCredits, rate);` on line 9, you are sending in two parameters. But inside the actual method below, you accept only one parameter. You need to change that to two parameters so your method accepts 2 parameters. Make another variable and call it c. So, `int c`. So now your method signature should look like this:

```
public static void tuitionBill(int c, double r){ ... }
```

Also, on line 11, I think you want to print tuition of other guy. So send in `yourCredits` variable instead of `myCredits`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parameter c on the tuitionBill method.